# Develop and Production Firebase database with Google SignIn

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-signin

As we all know, we should not work directly on the Production Version of a Database, so we keep things separated: One Database for Development and another one for Production.

But how does it work with Firebase and especially when using Google SignIn ?

So far, I have pointed my debug and release version to two different Firebase Database, both with a different google-services.json file etc.

When logging with Email and Password on the Release Version, no problem.
However, when Logging with Google SignIn on the Release Version, the logging fails.

How do you guys do?
Is there something to know or be cautious about?
So far, I'm thinking it may come from the SHA1 key fingerprint passed to the Release Database. Which one to pass, the release one?

Cheers

Andy

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the SHA1 key fingerprint of your release key that you are using on google play store to the **Firebase console** > **project settings** > **apps** > select your app package and add your SHA1 key fingerprint in the existing list of your SHA1 certificates.

Then click save, download new google_service.json from upper right corner and paste it into your Project's app folder. Clean build and enjoy creating and running your release apk.